# How to write a query to check database value with session value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone help me? I am taking a session value in variable like

```
var user = Session["UserName"];
```

and by this i will get username of an employee who is logged in. Now I want designation of that employee so I wrote

```
var data=from u in db.EmployeeTabs.Where(p=>p.EmpName==user).Select(v=>v.Designation)
```

Now variable data will probably contain the designation of employee who is logged in. Now I want a condition, based on the condition I want to redirect the page so I want an if condition like

```
if(val(data)=="Receptionist")
```

then it should display a `Register.cshtml` page, so for that what should I write?
And where to write? Means in an controller? Or i should create some method in controller?

Comment: Consider reading a tutorial first, front to end. You ask very basic questions showing a lack of understanding on how asp.net mvc works. That can not be remedied with an answer here, only by you behaving borderline professional and learning to use your tool, by reading documentation and tutorials.

Comment: can u give me any tutorial's link to read the concepts????

Comment: [Introduction to ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1).

Comment: Off topic note: please stop adding noise to posts, like "Any idea??" or "thanks". It cause your edits to be rejected, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2264825).

Comment: Ok. sorry for my mistake. I'll take care of it from next time. Thanks @Shadow Wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) Making some assumptions about your code, I think you want something like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{          
    var user = Session["User"];
    using (var db = new YourEntity())
    {
        var data = from u in db.EmployeeTabs.Where(p => p.EmpName == user).Select(v => v.Designation);
        if (data == null)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Register");
        }

        Switch(data.First().Designation)
        {
           case "Receptionist":
               return RedirectToAction(Register);
        }
   }

   return View();
}

public public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: thnx for the answer.it is really useful